# Why does Python give 3 different lines from outputWriter instead of overwriting the lines?

Tags: python, csv, automation

I am learning how to import information into .csv files with Python. I have the following code:

```
import csv

outputFile = open('output.csv','w',newline = '')
outputWriter = csv.writer(outputFile)
outputWriter.writerow(['spam','eggs','bacon','ham'])
outputWriter.writerow(['Hello World!','eggs','bacon','ham'])
outputWriter.writerow([1,2,3.141592,4])
outputFile.close()
```

My csv file looks like this:

[image]

Why does it output in 3 individual rows instead of overwriting the 1st row each time? How would I get it to overwrite if I wanted to?

Thank you for your insight from a beginner.

Comment: Why would you expect it to overwrite? You never back up in the file.

Comment: Do you think that `newline=''` means not to add a newline after writing? It means to use the default newline character for the OS.

Comment: Does that newline = ' ', just make it a new row every time? Do you know if I can designate a certain row to print to?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `seek()` to go back to the beginning of the file before writing each row.

```
import csv

outputFile = open('output.csv','w',newline = '')
outputWriter = csv.writer(outputFile)
outputWriter.writerow(['spam','eggs','bacon','ham'])
outputFile.seek(0)
outputWriter.writerow(['Hello World!','eggs','bacon','ham'])
outputFile.seek(0)
outputWriter.writerow([1,2,3.141592,4])
outputFile.truncate() # clear out any remnants of previous lines.
outputFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that behavior is from the csv library, if you want to write in one line, you could try this:

```py
with open("output.csv","w") as writer:
    writer.write(",".join(['spam','eggs','bacon','ham']))
    writer.write(",".join(['Hello World!','eggs','bacon','ham']))
    writer.write(",".join(['1','2','3.141592','4']))
```

Additionally, if you want to use CSV library you could try to do this:

```py
import csv

# Create 1 list from the other 3
list1 = ['spam','eggs','bacon','ham']
list2 = ['Hello World!','eggs','bacon','ham']
list3 = [1,2,3.141592,4]
completeList = list1 + list2 + list3

# Write that list into one line
outputFile = open('output.csv','w',newline = '')
outputWriter = csv.writer(outputFile)
outputWriter.writerow(completeList)
```

**Edit:**
This is the result I got from both approaches.

[image: Result]

If you are not reaching this result. It is probable that your list elements contain some line break "\n" inside them. I am not sure where you are reading your lists as inputs. If you have any input it would be worthy if you post it as well.

Comment: Hi Friend, when I write the code as you have it here, I am still getting it in 3 different lines. Thoughts? Thank you for your help, I've only been programming for a few weeks, now!

Comment: Really? With both approaches I got just one line